# mongo find() producing no output with eval

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a 'find all' of resources within a mongodb collection.

I can get the count ok:

```
mongo ip:port/database1 -u correctusername -p correctpassword 
--authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.getCollection('collection_123').count()"
```

But when I try to tweak it,

```
mongo ip:port/database1 -u correctusername -p correctpassword 
--authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.getCollection('collection_123').find()"
```

It produces

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.0
connecting to: ip:port/database1
DBQuery: database1.collection_123 -> { }
```

I also tried `find({})`

There doesn't seem to be authentication errors. The first query works and produces a count. I can also

```
mongo ip:port/database1 -u correctusername -p correctpassword 
--authenticationDatabase admin
```

get into the mongo shell and

```
db.getCollection('collection_123').find()
```

And see the correct json output.

Comment: Care to give the collection name? It this really table123?

Comment: @Oct updated it to collection, it's just a test collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have found is to

```
mongo  ip:port/database1 -u correctusername -p correctpassword
--authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.collection.find().forEach(printjson)"
```

but the output is not the same as  in the shell, as further commands will not work, like sort or limit.

**Update**

A better solution is

```
mongo  ip:port/database1 -u correctusername -p correctpassword
--authenticationDatabase admin --eval "printjson(db.collection.find().toArray())"
```